# IIS Reverse Proxy for the Play Framework

Tags: iis, playframework, proxy

I have a play application that I would like to set up on an IIS server. I want to set up an reverse proxy. In Apache I would do something like this:

```
ProxyPass /myapp localhost:9000/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp localhost:9000/myapp
```

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="IIS reverse proxy for play framework" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(appName.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9000/{R:1}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".+" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```